# DD-WRT routers - How can I specify any/all IP address ranges?

Tags: router, ip, port-forwarding, dd-wrt, wildcards

I'm creating port forwarding rules on my DD-WRT router (shown below) and want to allow all (any) source networks access.  My thought was to specify 0.0.0.0/32 but that is not working.  How do I specify this?

[image]

Comment: try alex's edit to his answer about leaving the field blank or trying 0.0.0.0/0  Leaving the field source net blank is also mentioned in a post here http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=509730

Comment: That works! I originally had tried this and thought it did not work, but I insufficiently tested it.

Comment: Does 0.0.0.0/0 also work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no "wildcards" for specifying IP address ranges. You need to use subnets instead. You can see examples of subnets in the "Source Net" column.

So instead of `192.168.*.*` you need to use `192.168.0.0/16`

in DD-WRT I believe you need to leave the field blank in order to set it to `0.0.0.0/0`

Comment: Yup, I realized that after I posted and just edited the question.  It's the means of specifying all/any source networks that I want to determine.

Comment: have you tried to leave it blank?

Comment: That works!  I originally had tried this and thought it did not work, but I insufficiently tested it.  I'm going to mark your answer as accepted.  Maybe you could edit your response to move the 'in DD-WRT I believe you need to leave the field blank in order to set it to 0.0.0.0/0' sentence to the top, or perhaps remove everything else.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to leave this field blank.

I had the exact same question when using the dd-wrt.v24-**18946**_NEWD-2_K2.6_mega-nv60k firmware on my linksys e3000.  For some odd reason using the same port forwarding settings I've used in previous dd-wrt builds did not result in appropriate port forwarding (i.e. nmap always showed my router's external port 80 as filtered).  I thought it was likely due to the new source_net field.  I was wrong.  No combination of subnet settings fixed the problem.  I finally fixed things by upgrading my firmware using the ddwrt database as opposed to brainslayer's svn site (the database ended up being more current).  I'm currently running dd-wrt.v24-**21061**_NEWD-2_K2.6_mega-nv60k and port forwarding works without any entry in the source_net field.